# Single field Access

Tags: fields

I have a field "Passed deal review". This field should be edited by only one user. When others try to edit it, it should throw an error message. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create this field as **read only** (not granting edit permissions on field accessibility) and then grant those permission via **permission set** to the user you want to be able to modify it.

Personally I think it's cleaner than showing an error. If you still wanna try do it though You can do a validation rule `ONCHANGED()` and exclude the user you want to be able to modify it by Profile(if it's unique),  id, name or any criteria you find suitable.